# Error applying AWS Elastic Beanstalk settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

For a while now, every time I try to make a modification in my Elastic Beanstalk environment, I get this message and it does not allow me to save anything

Invalid option value: '' (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default', OptionName: 'MatcherHTTPCode'): Value does not satisfy regex: '^((\d{3}(-\d{3})?)|(\d{3}(,\d{3})*))$' [The configured value for 'MatcherHTTPCode' is invalid. A valid value must be a single code of 3 digits, a comma separated list of codes (e.g 200,210), or a range of codes (e.g 200-210).]
`aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default:MatcherHTTPCode`

PHP 7.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.1

[error catch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnyFX.png)

Comment: Is your EB application configured to use an `application load balancer` or `network load balancer`? You would first define this via the `Configuration > Capacity > Environment Type` setting. If that was set to `Load Balanced` you would then need to modify additional settings in `Configuration > Load Balancer`

Comment: This can also be accomplished via `EC2 > Load Balancers` and `Target Groups`. Do any of the above situations apply to your application?